# Highchart Export

Tags: javascript, facebook, highcharts

I am trying to export Highchart.  I want to share my highchart as an image on Facebook and hence I am trying to generate the highchart link which I intend to post on Facebook as an image. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function createURL(activeTab){
var obj = {};
    var chart;

chart = $(activeTab).highcharts();
obj.svg = chart.getSVG();
obj.type = 'image/png';
obj.width = 450;
obj.async = true;


$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: chart.options.exporting.url,
    data: obj,
    success: function (data) {
        var exportUrl = this.url;
        urlToExport = exportUrl+data;
        FB.ui(
        {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
        link: urlToExport,
        message: ''
        });
    }
});


     }
```

I am getting the following error: TypeError: chart is undefined

Where am I going wrong ?

**Update**
I have created a javascript function to fetch my highchart. My code for fetchning the highchart is as follows:

```
    function setPriceParameterAndDisplay(){
document.getElementById('progressbarPrice').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('containerPrice').style.display='block';;
            Highcharts.chart('containerPrice', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: StockHeading ,
    },
    subtitle: {
         text: '<a style=\"color:blue;\" href=\"https://www.alphavantage.co\">Source: Alpha Vantage</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: XAxisData,
          minTickInterval: 6,

   showLastLabel: true,

    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Stock Price',
        },
        tickInterval: 5,
        min:null,


         },{
        title: {
            text: 'Volume '
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}m',
        },
        opposite:true,
         tickInterval: 50,
        min:0,

    }],
    plotOptions: {
    area:{
    threshold:null,},
    label: {
    enabled: false,
},
        line: {

            enableMouseTracking: true
        },
        series: {
        marker: {
                enabled: false
            },}
    },

    series: [{
        name: symbol,
        label: {
    enabled: false,
},
        type: 'area',
        color: '#F66464',
        data: PriceData,
        tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }

    }, {
        name: symbol + ' Volume' ,
        label: {
    enabled: false,
},
        type: 'column',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
         yAxis: 1,
        data: StockVolume,
        tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }


    }]
});};
```

Comment: Have you retrieved your chart via jQuery properly? What is the content of the `chart` variable after this line: `chart = $(activeTab).highcharts();`?

Comment: Yes, I have retrieved my chart using jQuery. On console it says that chart is undefined after chart = $(activeTab).highcharts();

Comment: This means that you don't fetch it properly. Please share the HTML code of the container for the chart.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @KamilKulig any update ?

Comment: You're using `activeTab` object to fetch the object via jQuery. I don't see it defined anywhere in the code that you attached as an update. What is it?

Comment: On click of button:
var activeTab = $('.nav-tabs li.active a').attr("href");
createURL(activeTab);

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(activeTab)` after the line that you posted in your latest comment? Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It'll help you to format your questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    if (Highcharts.getOptions().exporting) {
        let contextButton = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton;

        contextButton.menuItems = contextButton.menuItems.filter((item) => {
            console.log(item)
            return item.textKey === 'downloadCSV' || item.textKey === 'downloadPNG';
        });
    }

} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

Try this code inside your function

Comment: I think more details about what you actually did and what is your code doing would be useful for the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the solution for you as a jsfiddle. Please have a look and give me thumbs up. The main issue was, I think, that you named the wrong chart, now it's corrected here:

```
chart = $(containerPrice).highcharts();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jxcf5mgq/3/